# Заполнение двумерного массива / Векторизация текста

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Нужно заполнить двумерный массив. элемент с индексом `(i, j)` в этой матрице должен быть равен количеству вхождений j-го слова в i-е предложение. (предложения считываются из файла, разбиты на списки и все слова, встречающиеся в предложениях добавлены в словарь d, где ключ - это слово, а порядковый индекс значение).

входные данные 22 предложения, приведенных к спискам вида `['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']` в итоге должна получиться матрица 22х253 (22 - как предложений, 253 как всего уникальных слов, используемых в предложениях). Слова собраны в словарь вида [слово: индекс]. Если слово из словаря встречается в 1 предложении 2 раза, а его индекс по словарю 1, на месте элемента `m[1, 1]` должна стоять 2 и т.д.

Создала пустую матрицу и запустила перебор, но она все равно остается нулевой, не пойму где ошибка

```
m = np.zeros((number_line, len(new_line)))
i = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    for x in line:
        a = line.count(x)
        j = d[x]
        m[i, j] = a
    i += 1
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример входных данных и что должно получиться

Comment: входные данные несколько 22 предложения, приведенных к списку вида ['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process'] в итоге должна получиться матрица 22х253 (22 - как предложений, 253 как всего уникальных слов, используемых в предложениях). Слова собраны в словарь вида [слово: индекс]. Если слово из словаря встречается в 1 предложении 2 раза, а его индекс по словарю 1, на месте элемента m[1, 1] должна стоять 2 и т.д.

Comment: просил же в вопросе, а не в комментариях :) нажмите на кнопку `править` и там напишите, так и понятнее, и логичнее :)

Comment: спасибо) в чем проблема там не подскажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[По просьбе автора вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775003/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-python#comment1212086_775057) привожу пример решения с циклами.

```
import numpy as np
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
from collections import Counter

text = """Displays osx displays.
osx selection.
Nothing!
"""
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
tok = RegexpTokenizer('(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
vocab = {'displays':0, 'osx':1, 'selection':2}

res = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(vocab)))
for i,s in enumerate(sentences):
    for w,cnt in Counter(w.lower() for w in tok.tokenize(s)).items():
        if w in vocab.keys():
            res[i, vocab[w]] = cnt
```

Результат:

```
In [254]: res
Out[254]:
array([[ 2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [255]: vocab
Out[255]: {'displays': 0, 'osx': 1, 'selection': 2}
```

NOTE: для реальных задач лучше воспользоваться [другим решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775057/211923).

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) и [Pandas.SparseDataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html).

Для больших текстов - это будет работать на порядки быстрее (по сравнению с решением использующим вложенные циклы) и занимать на несколько порядков меньше памяти (итоговые данные представлены в виде **разреженной** (`sparse`) матрицы)

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

sentences = [
  "'It's Raining Cats and Dogs",
  "Do cats like dogs or hot dogs?",
  "Cats prefer hot dogs!"
]

cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(sentences),
                       columns=cv.get_feature_names(),
                       default_fill_value=0)
```

Результат:

```
In [201]: r
Out[201]:
   cats  dogs  hot  like  prefer  raining
0     1     1    0     0       0        1
1     1     2    1     1       0        0
2     1     1    1     0       1        0
```

Comment: Спасибо. А через цикл нет шансов  добить?

Comment: Жаль, мне б хоть подсказку

Comment: @Flower, OK, у вас исходные данные в виде списка списков?

Comment: Исходные данные предложения в файле каждое с новой строки. Каждое предложение я перевела в список. потом из всех собрала все встречающиеся слова без повторов в словарь d вида [слово: индекс]

Comment: @Flower, приведите небольшой пример данного словаря в вашем вопросе...

Comment: {'displays': 155, 'osx': 192, 'selection': 67}

Comment: @Flower, а что обозначает индекс? Как понять в каком предложении встретилось слово ?

Comment: Вот эта матрица должна получиться 22x254. 22 предложения 254 слова. Номер из словаря должен служить координатой j элемента матрицы, а порядковый номер строки(предложения) координатой i. т.е. берем например 'osx'. он во всех предложениях будет в 192 столбце. если оно встречается в предложении 1 два раза, то значение элемента матрицы m[1, 192] должно быть 2.