# Количество слов в строке с учетом повторений в python

Tags: python

Дано: текст, представленный списком из нескольких строк; список всех уникальных слов этого текста.

Необходимо: построить матрицу размерностью ((количество строк текста - i, количество уникальных слов - j)) ij-элемент которой равен количеству повторений j-того слова в i-той строке.

Промежуточное решение такое:

```
import numpy as np
import re

# Открытие файла в режиме чтения
text_1 = open("sentences.txt", "r")    


# Список, в котором будут храниться строки текста
text_lower_2=[]                       

for line in text_1:
text_lower_2.append(line.lower())   


# Список, хранящий все слова-числа, которые будут исключены
numbers=[]                            

for number in text_lower_2:                     #
numbs=re.findall(r'\b(\d+)\b', number)
for num in numbs:
    numbers.append(num)


# Список, хранящий все буквенные слова поэлементно с исключением слов-чисел   
text_sep_words_3=[]                    
for line in text_lower_2:
words=re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', line)

for word in words:
    if word not in numbers and True:
        text_sep_words_3.append(word)


# Список, хранящий уникальные слова в тексте (удаление дублированных слов)           
text_uniq_words_4=[]                   
for word in text_sep_words_3:
if word not in text_uniq_words_4:
       text_uniq_words_4.append(word)


#Создаем объект dict уникальных слов из списка уникальных слов 
text_indexed_words_5={}
index=1
for word in text_uniq_words_4:
text_indexed_words_5[index]=word
index+=1


# Создаем матрицу, элементы которой отражают частоту использования каждого из уникальных слов
# в каждой строке текста
word_array=np.zeros((len(text_lower_2),len(text_indexed_words_5)))
# Счетчики строк и столбцов матрицы
i=1
j=1

# Для каждой строки текста...
for line in text_lower_2:
# ...внутри каждой итерации создается список слов, находящихся в строке...
line_sepd=re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', line)
# ... и для каждой пары "ключ-значение" из словаря уникальных слов...
for k,v in text_indexed_words_5.items():
    # ...если слово не находится в списке слов отдельной строки...
    j=k-1
    if v not in line_sepd:
        # ... в матрицу в координату i - номер строки k - номер уникального слова вписывается 0
        word_array[i][j]=0
    # ...иначе....    
    else:
        #....для каждого слова в отдельной строке.... 
        n=0
        for word in line_sepd:
            #print(word)
            # ...если слово строки совпадает с проверяемым словом, то оно засчитывается....
            if word==v:
                n+=1
        word_array[i][j]=n
i+=1
```

Но оно не дает корректного результата... Никак не могу найти ошибку.

**PS задача стоит сделать такую программу только силами модуля `re`**

Comment: "сделайте все за меня"?

Comment: не, идею просто подсказать прошу

Comment: Наследуетесь от `dict()`, изменяете метод `__setitem__()` так, чтобы при добавлении в словарь проверялось существование, и, соответственно, +1 в value вместо добавления.

Comment: @0andriy, из collections словарь Counter?

Comment: @gil9red ну вот, всё сделано до нас!

Comment: Решение хорошее, но задача стоит сделать такую программу только силами модуля re

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775003/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%92%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @StepanSokol, я переоткрыл вопрос. Я правильно вас понял - вы не хотите использовать никакие модули (включая встроенные) кроме `re`?

Comment: Именно так. Задачу я все-таки решил