# Подсчитать количество каждого слова, использованного в столбце датафрейма

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Мне как-то нужно объединить все слова в столбце "tokenized_review" и посчитать количество каждого использованного слова.[image: таблица с данными]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775057/211923

Comment: Код и данные в вопросе должны быть представлены в воспроизводимом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому-то интересно, нашел ответ:
Сперва переобразуем все данные в столбце в string:

```
new_list = shipping['tokenized_review'].astype(str).tolist()
```

Далее используем следующее:

```
import collections, re
bagsofwords = [ collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', txt))
        for txt in new_list]
sumbags = sum(bagsofwords, collections.Counter())
sumbags
```